# Difference in Interaction Effect in lme4

Tags: mixed-model, interaction, lme4-nlme

I've the following problem which I want to analyze:

Sales of a company depends on quantity of product A and B plus advertisement. All these 3 independent variables are continuous variables. Now, There are 3 cities in which products are been sold. So, I want to check the fixed effect interaction of product A and B with city. I was using the following formula for the specification of the model.

```
model1 <- lmer( sales ~ prodA + prodB + advert + prodA * city, data=modelData)

model2 <- lmer( sales ~ prodA + prodB + advert + prodA : city, data=modelData)
```

In both the cases I was getting the interaction result for prodA.

My question is what's the difference between the 2 specifications?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `lmer()`, like `lm()`, `variableA : variableB` is only the interaction term. And `variableA * variableB` is the same as `variableA + variableB + variableA : variableB`. `*` includes variables individually as well as their interaction term in the regression model. Notice that all three expressions `variableA + variableB + variableA * variableB`, `variableA * variableB` and `variableA + variableB + variableA : variableB` yield same results. So, your two models are equivalent.